# Replace function for replacing characters in any combination

Tags: python

I am working with genetic data. I am trying to create a function that replaces the 1st,2nd, and 3rd characters of a string in any combination. Additionally, I was hoping to avoid replacing a character that is already in that position.

So I have code that will take a string of nucleotides and split them into groups of three nucleotides.

```
import more_itertools as mit
with open('test_data_cdna.fa.txt', "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        li=line.strip()
        a = ["".join(codon) for codon in mit.windowed(li, 3)]
        for x in a:
            print(x)
```

For each group of 3 nucleotides, I am trying to essentially simulate all combinations of mutations in those 3 nucleotides. So for example, if the first 3 nucleotides are `ATG` I was hoping to produce an output similar to this (excluding the carrots, the carrots are just there to make it easier to see visualize what is happening)

Replacing the first character (carrots indicate which character was replaced):

```
TTG
^
GTG
^
CTG
^
ATG <- skip or delete because same character was replaced as original 
^
```

Replacing the second character:

```
AAG
 ^
AGG
 ^
ACG
 ^
ATG <- skip or delete because same character was replaced as original  
 ^
```

Replacing the third character:

```
ATA
  ^
ATT
  ^
ATC
  ^
ATG <- skip or delete because same character was replaced as original 
  ^
```

list of characters to be used for replacement

```
['A','T','G','C']
```

Starting string:

```
ATG
```

I was hoping to just output each replacement into a new file. With each line of the file being a 3 letter string

Expected output file:

```
TTG
GTG
CTG
AAG
AGG
ACG
ATA
ATT
ATC
```

Example data:

```
ATGGCCGCGGCGCCGGGAGGGTCAGCGCAGCCCGCTGGCCCCGGCCCGCGCCTGGGTTTC
AGCACCGCGGACAGCGGCGTCGGCATGAGCGGGCTAAACCCCGGTCCCGCCGTACCCATG
AAGGACCACGACGCCATCAAGCTCTTCGTGGGGCAGATCCCGCGGGGCTTGGACGAGCAG
GACCTCAAGCCGCTGTTCGAGGAGTTCGGCCGCATCTACGAGCTGACGGTGCTGAAGGAC
CGGCTCACCGGCCTCCACAAAGGCTGTGCCTTCCTCACCTACTGCGCCCGGGACTCTGCT
CTCAAGGCCCAGAGTGCACTGCACGAGCAGAAGACCCTGCCAGGGATGAATCGTCCGATC
CAAGTGAAGCCAGCTGCCAGTGAGGGCCGAGGAGAGGACCGAAAGCTGTTTGTGGGGATG
CTGGGCAAGCAGCAGGGTGAGGAGGACGTCAGACGCCTGTTCCAGCCCTTTGGCCACATC
GAGGAGTGCACGGTCCTGCGGAGTCCTGACGGCACCAGTAAAGGCTGTGCCTTTGTGAAG
TTCGGGAGTCAAGGGGAAGCTCAGGCGGCCATCCGGGGTCTGCACGGCAGCCGGACCATG
GCGGGCGCCTCGTCCAGCCTCGTGGTCAAGCTGGCGGACACCGACCGGGAGCGCGCGCTG
CGGCGGATGCAGCAGATGGCCGGCCACCTGGGCGCCTTCCACCCCGCGCCACTGCCGCTA
GGGGCCTGCGGCGCCTACACCACGGCGATCCTGCAGCACCAGGCGGCCCTGCTGGCGGCG
GCACAGGGCCCAGGCCTAGGCCCGGTGGCGGCAGTGGCGGCCCAGATGCAACACGTGGCG
GCCTTTAGCCTGGTAGCTGCGCCTCTGTTGCCCGCGGCAGCAGCCAACTCCCCGCCTGGC
AGCGGCCCTGGCACCCTCCCAGGTCTTCCGGCGCCCATCGGGGTCAATGGATTCGGCCCT
CTGACCCCCCAGACCAATGGCCAGCCGGGCTCCGACACGCTCTACAATAACGGGCTCTCC
CCTTATCCAGCCCAGAGCCCCGGCGTGGCTGACCCCCTGCAGCAGGCCTACGCTGGGATG
CACCACTACGCAGGCCCCGAAGGCTGTAACCTCTTCATCTATCACCTGCCTCAGGAGTTT
GGTGATGCGGAACTCATACAGACATTCCTGCCCTTTGGAGCCGTTGTCTCTGCTAAAGTC
TTTGTGGATCGAGCCACCAACCAGAGCAAGTGTTTTGGGTTTGTTAGTTTTGACAATCCA
ACTAGTGCCCAGACTGCTATTCAGGCGATGAATGGCTTTCAAATTGGCATGAAGAGGCTC
AAGGTCCAGCTAAAGCGGCCCAAGGATGCCAACCGGCCTTACTGA
```

Comment: Can you clarify your intended output, please? Are you looking to make one long file, or perhaps one output file for each nucleotide trio in the input? If one file, do you want any kind of separator between the results from each input trio?

Comment: Just updated the question. Just one long file. No need for any separation between each trio or separate files per trio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a generator function that generates all those mutations you are asking:

```py
def mutation(nucs):
    replacements = "ATGC"
    for i in range(0, len(nucs)):
        for r in replacements:
            if (nucs[i] == r): continue
            yield nucs[:i] + r + nucs[i+1:]
```

You can use it like this:

```py
for n in mutation("ATG"):
    print(n)
```

Output:

```
TTG
GTG
CTG
AAG
AGG
ACG
ATA
ATT
ATC
```

Edit: Sorry I didn't see you want to write the output to a file. It's trivial though. You can do something like this:

```py
def save_mutations(nucs, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        for n in mutation("ATG"):
            f.write(n + "\n")
```

Comment: This works but there isn't just was trio of nucleotides, there is much more. I need a way perform this on all the trios

Comment: I don't quite follow. What's stopping you from calling this function on each trio of nucleotides?

Comment: @AlpacaMax I apologize, I had a small mistake when I was trying to run your answer! This works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
def replacing(i, j):
    return "".join([chr if k!=i else chrs[j] for k, chr in enumerate(input_chr)])
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrs = 'ATGC'
    input_chr = "ATG"

    n = len(input_chr)
    m = len(chrs)

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            output = replacing(i, j)
            print(output)
```

To optimise the code use directly strings (it is the same behavior of list for when the element is one chr.